# Apache Camel + JBoss Fuse - Routing between CXFRS component and bean component - IOException stream closed

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, cxfrs

I have written a CXF REST service that returns application/json configured as follows:

ProspectGenerator:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/consume")
public Prospect convertProspectToJson(Prospect prospect,@QueryParam("customerType") String customerType){

    //DTO logic goes here
    System.out.println("Prospect obj received.."+prospect.getProspectName());

    prospect.setCustomerType(customerType);

    return prospect;

}
```

This service works when deployed into JBoss Fuse.

**Now I have a Camel Route builder as follows:**

```
public class ServiceRouter extends RouteBuilder {

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder#configure()
 */
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("jetty://http://localhost:8182/route/prospect?bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer")
    //The Raw type to String conversion is done here. Refer the class for details
    //Processor converts the Message from byte[] to String
    .process(new ResponseToStringProcessor())
    .unmarshal("jsonDataformat") //jsonDataformat - bean in blueprint XML for converting to requested object type
    .to("cxfrs://http://localhost:8181/cxf/prospect/consume")
    /*1) The above line has the BodyType as Cxf's ResponseImpl instead of Prospect Object
    * 2) The below bean accepts type only as Prospect object and hence I get exception */
    .to("bean:prospectService?method=doSomething");

}
```

**ProspectService:**

```
public class ProspectService {
    public void doSomething(@Body Prospect prospect){

    System.out.println("Prospect Service got the request.."+prospect.getCustomerType());

    }
}
```

***I get the following exception on trying to route to the bean defined:***

*org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: com.karthik.bo.Prospect but has value: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl@54c96476 of type*

**How do I resolve this error? I can't figure out how to convert the ResponseImpl to my POJO. The came trace shows:**

*BodyType:org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl, Body:{"prospect":{"customerType":"VIP","prospectId":999,"prospectName":"karthik"}}*

**I tried converting ResponseImpl to String(that will contain JSON payload), but I always end up in IOException stream is closed.** - *Code of conversion below:*

```
public void convert(Exchange exchange){

InputStream is =  (InputStream)exchange.getIn().getBody(ResponseImpl.class).getEntity();

String s="";
try {
    s = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(is);
    is.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("in convertor..."+s);

}
```

---

After lots of failure attempts(mentioned in the comments), The final solution was to write a FallBackCoverter as follows - ***This didn't throw Stream closed IOException, which couldn't be explained to self.***

```
@FallbackConverter
    public static <T> T convertTo(Class<T> type, Exchange exchange, Object value, TypeConverterRegistry registry){

        System.out.println("Checking fall backconverter");
        if (ResponseImpl.class.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) {
            TypeConverter tc = registry.lookup(type, ResponseImpl.class);
            if (tc == null && type.getName().equals("com.karthik.bo.Prospect")) {
                Prospect prospect=new Prospect();
                try(InputStream is =  (InputStream)((ResponseImpl)value).getEntity()) {
                    if(is!=null){
                        String s = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(is);
                        if(s!=null && s.length()>0){
                            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                            prospect = mapper.readValue(s, Prospect.class);

                        }
                        is.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception occured"+e.getMessage());
                }
                return type.cast(prospect);
            }
        }

        return (T) Void.TYPE;
    }
```

**and my Router was modified to:**

```
from("jetty://http://localhost:8182/route/prospect?bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer")
        //The Raw type to String conversion is done here. Refer the class for details
        .process(new ResponseToStringProcessor())
        .unmarshal("jsonDataformat")
        .to("cxfrs://http://localhost:8181/cxf/prospect/consume")
        .convertBodyTo(Prospect.class)
        .to("bean:prospectService?method=doSomething")
        .marshal("jsonDataformat");
```

---

I couldn't mark this as solution without confirming if this is the only way to do. My solution was implemented after I found a old JIRA issue in camel-cxf

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-3208

I had to write a FallBackConvertor for this purpose.

Comment: My several approach of converting the ResponseImpl which had InputStream as body failed. I tried following : 

1) In process method, extracted the ResponseImpl and tried to convert the InputStream to String using IOUtils.toString().. - failed as threw IOException - stream closed

2) Tried invoking a bean component that accepts ResponseImpl as body and tried same conversion as above - failed

3) Tried to write a TypeConvertor for camel for this conversion - fails with same exception - stream closed

All the above approaches were failing and I got no idea, why would the stream be closed.

Comment: The only workaround that helped me was - Writing a Fallbacktype convertor that did the same operation of converting the ResponseImpl to InputStream and from InputStream to String and from String(Json) to my BO using ObjectMapper of jackson. Though this works, I couldn't accept this as a valid solution as I had to do so much conversion for a simple JSON returned from cxfrs:uri

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your call might not be getting picked up via reflection on the service class.  I'm not sure exactly what your conversion class is attempting to do, but have you tried just adding a provider on to the end of your client/server to handle the Json to POJO mapping?  Let me post a simple example that worked for me (I did this in blueprint, but it should work similarly for DSL).  Excuse the state of the code, I am still doing a lot of testing to find what works and doesn't work.

Here I have both a cxf rs client and server:

```
<cxf:rsClient id="rsClient" address="${CXFclient}" serviceClass="com.limelight.esb.servicedb.services.ServiceDBExternalRestService"
    loggingFeatureEnabled="true" loggingSizeLimit="500">
    <cxf:providers>
        <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider" />
    </cxf:providers>
</cxf:rsClient>

<cxf:rsServer id="rsServer" address="${CXFserver}${serverService}" serviceClass="com.limelight.esb.servicedb.services.ServiceDBRestService"
    loggingFeatureEnabled="true" loggingSizeLimit="500">
    <cxf:providers>
        <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider" />
    </cxf:providers>
</cxf:rsServer>
```

My route looks like the following:

```
    <route id="servicedb.rest.company.get.route">
        <from uri="{{servicedb.rest.company.get}}" />
        <log message="Rest getCompany called." />
        <to uri="{{servicedb.company.get}}" />
        <removeHeader headerName="Content-Length" />
    </route>
```

And finally my service class:

```
@Path("/servicedb/")
public class ServiceDBRestService {
    @GET
    @Path("company/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public ServiceDBCompanyResponse getCompanyRest(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        //just an interface
        return null;
    }
}
```

This could also be related to the header for the expected response object.  For that you could use a custom pre-processor to modify that and just add it into the route before you make the call out.

```
public class ServiceDBProcessors implements Processor {

@Override
public void process(Exchange exchng) throws Exception {        
    exchng.getIn().setHeader("CamelCxfRsResponseClass", your.class.here.class);
}
```

}
Now, the reason I stumbled across this item is I did encounter this problem when making a call via soap, which I had to play around with quite a bit until I found your solution here.  If the above doesn't help, I can at least provide a slightly better answer that removes a bit of the conversion.  I found you can put another handler after the return to do your conversion and it should be picked up with reflection if your input parameter is a string.  I had to write a class like the following:

```
    public ServiceDBCompany convertCompany(String companyResponseBody) {
        ServiceDBCompany newCompany = new ServiceDBCompany();
        if(companyResponseBody!=null && companyResponseBody.length()>0){
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            try {
                ServiceDBCompanyResponse company = mapper.readValue(companyResponseBody, ServiceDBCompanyResponse.class);
                newCompany.setCompanyId(company.getCompanyId());
                newCompany.setName(company.getCompanyName());
            } catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception reading body, returning null " + ServiceDBCompany.class);
            }
        }
        return newCompany;
}
```

Hope this at least gives you a few ideas of solutions you can try!

Comment: Hi @Kendall Rogers,Thank you.Your solution would probably work coz it's sort of another conversion which is a work around we both have been trying to do in converting it to a simple required object.

Since, this approach has failed and it's been a longer time, we tried with other options with cxf:dataFormats etc. When started fresh with the project, we never stubled upon this error again. 

I couldn't use cxfrs:provider as I ws using java DSL with jetty component and not cxfrs component of camel.Yes,we used cxfrs component and went ahead without this error. I appreciate your help. Thank you :)